# Update the Multiline Text field to Rich Text in SharePoint Document Libray

Tags: document-library, modern-experience, pnp-powershell, multiline-text-field

I want to update the Multiline Text field to Rich Text in the Document library using PnP PowerShell.

I tried to find the property which can do the trick but did not have any luck.

Can someone help me identify which property I need to set up while using PnP PowerShell?

[Set-PnPField](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Set-PnPField.html#examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two properties needs to be set in Schema i.e. **RichText** to **TRUE** and **RichTextMode** to **FullHtml**. Those property you can't set it directly via **Set-PnPField** so you need to get existing schema first and you need to update two attribute accordingly.

You can try below script to do so.

```
$libraryURL = "Shared Documents"
$internalName = "TestField2"
$field = Get-PnPField -List $libraryURL -Identity $internalName
[xml]$schemaXml = $field.SchemaXml
$schemaXml.Field.SetAttribute("RichTextMode", "FullHtml")
$schemaXml.Field.SetAttribute("RichText", "TRUE")
Set-PnPField -List $libraryURL -Identity $internalName -Values @{SchemaXml=$schemaXml.OuterXml}
```

Took hint from https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/issues/2701#issuecomment-637561473

Comment: thanks Kalpesh Vaghela. 
I also had to modify the property IsolateStyles to true
$schemaXml.Field.SetAttribute("IsolateStyles", "TRUE")